# Is it possible to specify errors for individual InlinePanel items?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

I know that errors can be added to the general admin form by using a custom form class (subclassing `WagtailAdminModelForm`) and using `self.add_error("<field_name>", "<error_message>")`. However is it also possible to add error message to the inline form items of an inline panel?

For example in my case it is forbidden to add duplicate entries in the inline panel. When the user adds duplicate items and tries to submit, all duplicate items should be highlighted with an error message.

Edit: I need to do this for a `Snippet` (not a `Page`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a unique together constraint on the *Orderable* class that checks the *ParentalKey* field against the field that needs to be unique. Wagtail display an error above the orderable list and an error on each of the subsequent duplicate fields (but not the first).

For example, I have a `TemplateTextSetItem` Orderable class with a ParentalKey field `set` that points to a ClusterableModel class:

```
class TemplateTextSetItem(Orderable):
    set = ParentalKey(
        "TemplateText",
        related_name="templatetext_items",
        help_text=_("Template Set to which this item belongs."),
        verbose_name="Set Name",
    )
    template_tag = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text=_("Enter a tag without spaces, consisting of lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.\nThe first character must be a lowercase letter."),
        verbose_name="Template Tag",
    )    
    text = models.TextField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_("The text to be inserted in the template.")
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('template_tag'),
        FieldPanel('text'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.template_tag

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('set', 'template_tag')
```

If I enter a duplicate value for `template_tag` within the same parent `TemplateText` instance, I would get the following result:

[image]

(1, 2 & 3 all have the same `template_tag` value, 2 & 3 have field errors displayed on the form)

If I was to enter 'test1' in a different parent instance, no error would be raised since it is unique in that instance.

`unique_together` actually has a deprecation warning in Django and should be written as:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['set', 'template_tag'], 
            name='unique_set_template_tag'
            )
    ]
```

Currently, Wagtail doesn't handle errors raised by `UniqueConstraint` and throws a 500 error instead. I think it might be coming in Wagtail 6.

Comment: I used `UniqueConstraint` and was wondering why it wouldn't show unique validation errors by default. Using `unique_together` does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The deprecation warning has been around since Django 2.2, I don't know why uptake has been so slow on this. It's embedded into every translatable model unfortunately and needed to handle translatable unique fields as well.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together